# Одинаковые буквы

Tags: c#

Как сделать проверку одинаковых букв в слове? Нужно вывести число с их количеством

Comment: В цикле пройтись по строке попутно суммируя кол-во встречаемости.

Comment: Заведите словарь, где ключом будет буква и значением счетчик (начиная 0), проходитесь по символам и плюсуйте в значение

Answer (score 1):

Если в слове все буквы только из одного алфавита и в одном регистре, то можно вот такой фокус сделать

```
var counts = new int[35];
var str = "оченьдлинноеслово";
foreach (var c in str) counts[c - 'а']++;
for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++)
    if (counts[i] > 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"{(char)(i + 'а')} - {counts[i]}");
```

Вывод

```
в - 1
д - 1
е - 2
и - 1
л - 2
н - 3
о - 4
с - 1
ч - 1
ь - 1
```

Если регистры разные или несколько алфавитов (например, русский и английский) или не только буквы в слове - то замените массив словарем, но принцип будет тот же.